# Importing excel into datagridview WITH verification

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, import

Currently, I am able to import an excel file into my datagridview with a button. I have tried many different codes found online to import and finally found one that works, with minor touches. The biggest issue I am having is 'reading' the contents of the cells within the excel file and if there is a certain verification step that is something that I do not want, the program does not import the file.

for example, in column 1, if there is a number less than 0, the import should cancel.

or another example, if a column (that is only supposed to be numbers), has an entry of a letter, import should be cancelled.

In other languages, I can picture this to be simple If statements, but I am new to VB.

if someone could lead me in the right direction, that would be much appreciated

Main page that I used was;
[Importing Excel Data in Datagridview using VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942305/importing-excel-data-in-datagridview-using-vb-net)

my current code;

```
    Dim dbconnect As OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim dta As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    Dim dts As DataSet
    Dim excel As String
    Dim OpenFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog

    OpenFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    OpenFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"

    If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then

        Dim file As New FileInfo(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
        Dim FileName As String = OpenFileDialog.FileName
        ' Dim selectedrowcount As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)

        excel = file.FullName
        dbconnect = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'")
        dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Feuil1$]", dbconnect)
        ' dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", dbconnect)

        dts = New DataSet

        dta.Fill(dts, "[Feuil1$]")

        ' dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet1$]")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "[Feuil1$]"
        dbconnect.Close()

        DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"

                   DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter

        '   MsgBox("Data has been imported")

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: dts has your data in it...do your verifications after the fill command.  If it doesn't pass, don't assign it as the source of the data grid

Comment: Thank you for your input. I think I understand,
so after the fill command..would it be a method? created in another sub?

'after the fill command, just as you said
dta.Fill(dts, "[Feuil1$]")
verifyStep()


and I would have the definition for this function after 'end Sub' ?
or is it possible/better to do it all within this same Sub ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example from my comment.  Note that the close command was moved up.

In this case, the data is only bound to the grid if the data appears the way you want it to.

```
' Fill Data Set and Close Connection (I Moved the Close)
dts = New DataSet
dta.Fill(dts, "[Feuil1$]")
dbconnect.Close()

' Loop Through the Data And Make Sure Its Good
Dim dataSuccess as Boolean = True
Dim rowIndex as Integer = 0
For Each row as DataRow in dts.Tables(0).Rows

    If Convert.ToInt32(row(0)) < 0 Then
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Invalid Data in Row: " + rowIndex + " - 1st Column is Less Than Zero", "Data Import")
        dataSuccess = False
        Exit For
    End If

    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
Next

' If Its Good, Bind It
If dataSuccess Then

    DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "[Feuil1$]"

End If
```

Comment: thank you, this makes a lot of sense. I will try to work based off from this